# Is Possible to add menu without extending Activity in android

Tags: android, android-menu

I am creating custom control that `extends WebView`. I have referred may tutorials to add Menu in Android. But nothing found to add Menu in non-Activity class. `Is that possible to add the Menu in Non-Activity class?`

Comment: and why do you want to do this?

Comment: Inside the MyWebViewClient, i can get the neterror in OnReceiveError method. That time, i want to show one image and while pressing the refresh menu it should check the netconnection and reload the url again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not use `onCreateOptionsMenu()` in sub classes of WebView,but WebView extends `AbsoluteLayout`,so you can get dimensions of your window and (,when you need,) add some buttons at bottom of WebView sub class and it seems that is an option menu on your WebView.
Also you can use `window manager` to show specific layout on the window and user can interact with that layout that appear on top of your WebView.

Comment: thank you for your response hasan, could you please post any example for this?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no.
You should add the menu in the Activity where you are using the WebView.

You can read more about menus [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html).